# HLSL operator/functions cycle count

Tags: graphics, directx, hlsl

I'm modeling some algorithms to be run on GPU's. Is there a reference or something as to how many cycles the various intrinsics and calculations take on modern hardware? (nvidia 5xx+ series, amd 6xxx+ series) I cant seem to find any official word on this even though there are some mentions of the raised costs of normalization, square root and other functions throughout their documentation.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the cycle count documentation you're looking for either doesn't exist, or (if it does) it probably won't be as useful as you would expect. You're correct that some of the more complex GPU instructions take more time to execute than the simpler ones, but cycle counts are only important when instruction execution time is main performance bottleneck; GPUs are designed such that this is very rarely the case.

The way GPU shader programs achieve such high performance is by running many (potentially thousands) of shader threads in parallel. Each shader thread generally executes no more than a single instruction before being swapped out for a different thread. In perfect conditions, there are enough threads in flight that some of them are *always* ready to execute their next instruction, so the GPU never has to stall; this hides the latency of any operation executed by a single thread. If the GPU is doing useful work every cycle, then it's as if *every* shader instruction executes in a single cycle. In this case, the only way to make your program faster is to make it shorter (fewer instructions = fewer cycles of work overall).

Under more realistic conditions, when there isn't enough work to keep the GPU fully loaded, the bottleneck is virtually guaranteed to be memory accesses rather than ALU operations. A single texture fetch can take thousands of cycles to return in the worst case; with unpredictable stalls like that, it's generally not worth worrying about whether sqrt() takes more cycles than dot().

So, the key to maximizing GPU performance isn't to use faster instructions. It's about maximizing occupancy -- that is, making sure there's enough work to keep the GPU sufficiently busy to hide instruction / memory latencies. It's about being smart about your memory accesses, to minimize those agonizing round-trips to DRAM. And sometimes, when you're *really* lucky, it's about using fewer instructions.

Answer (score 0):

http://books.google.ee/books?id=5FAWBK9g-wAC&lpg=PA274&ots=UWQi5qznrv&dq=instruction%20slot%20cost%20hlsl&pg=PA210#v=onepage&q=table%20a-8&f=false

this is the closest thing i've found so far, it is outdated(sm3) but i guess better than nothing.

Answer (score -1):

does operator/functions have cycle? I know assembly instructions have cycle, that's the low level time measurement, and mostly depends on CPU.since operator and functions are all high level programming stuffs. so I don't think they have such measurement.

Comment: As far as i've gathered, HLSL is more closely related to assembly code than a high level language as far as the interpretation by hardware goes. It has been mentioned in nvidia documentation for the old 8xxx series that for example addmul and trig intrinsics are 1 cycle and both amd and nvidia use the formula of (number of flo's in addmul, 2) * shader clock * shader core count = theoretical peak flops as a part of their official specifications.